# what does the --db-file argument require exactly from the solana-tokens cli distribute-tokens command?

Tags: solana-cli

here's the crate i'm referring to:

https://lib.rs/crates/solana-tokens

there's no documentation on the --db-file argument of the solana-tokens distribute-tokens command, just trying to understand what exactly i need to include there

Answer (score 1):

The best is to eventually read through the code since it isn't extensively documented, but `--db-path` gives the path to a yml file which contains info about the token distribution, mainly processed transactions.  Feel free to add it to every command that you use for the same distribution! That way, you won't wrongly redo a token distribution.